# An issue with boost filesystem when linked statically

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I have the following code

```c
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

class A
{
public:
  A()
  {
    boost::filesystem::path exePath = boost::filesystem::read_symlink("/proc/self/exe");
  }
};

#if defined(GLOBAL_VER) && !defined(LOCAL_VER) 
A a;
#endif

int main()
{
#if !defined(GLOBAL_VER) && defined(LOCAL_VER)
  boost::filesystem::path exePath = boost::filesystem::read_symlink("/proc/self/exe");
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it with both flags `LOCAL_VER` and `GLOBAL_VER` and link it statically and dynamically. When I link it dynamically, program runs fine no problem

```
$ g++ test.cpp -I /boost/ -L /boost/stage/lib/ -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -DLOCAL_VER -o test ; ./test
$ g++ test.cpp -I /boost/ -L /boost/stage/lib/ -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -DGLOBAL_VER -o test ; ./test
```

When I link it statically, only the version which I compiled with `LOCAL_VER` runs fine while the program I compiled with `GLOBAL_VER` crashes.

```
$ g++ test.cpp -I /boost/ /boost/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a /boost/stage/lib/libboost_system.a -DLOCAL_VER -o test ; ./test
$ g++ test.cpp -I /boost/ /boost/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a /boost/stage/lib/libboost_system.a -DGLOBAL_VER -o test ; ./test
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm using g++ 4.7.2 on fc17, and boost 1.53 (which I downloaded and built). Any idea what is wrong? Is it a bug in boost or do I have a bug in my code?

Comment: My guess is that you're getting bitten by initialization order of some global that boost.filesystem is using.  It's kinda hard to tell without a stack trace though, you might try running it with gdb to get a better idea where it blew up :)

Comment: If so then how come it works when linked dynamically? Obviously there is no problem with the program when compiled with `LOCAL_VER` so this  shows that the line can be linked statically and should work. When compiled with `GLOBAL_VER` the dynamically linked program runs with no problem so this shows that it should be possible to run this line from a constructor of an object defined in the global scope. However, when linked statically the program crashes, why? Of course the problem is initialization, but I don't understand why it shows up only when linked in a specific way.

Comment: @ep271p314 "The relative order of initialization of non-local static objects defined in different translation units is undefined".  In other words, if boost defines a global (which qualifies as a "static object") there's simply no guarantee it will get initialized before your global.  With the dll version you're probably just getting lucky.

Comment: @ep271p314 ... either that or the cross-dll call in your global forces DllMain() to execute in the DLL, which would initialize all of the DLL globals.

Comment: @Nathan Monteleone, as far as I understand, it's not an issue of order between initializing global variables since there is only one translation unit which is `test.cpp` and boost has everything in a namespace and I'm not using it to avoid contamination. I don't think the dynamically linked program success is just luck, the results are quite consistent. This problem doesn't reproduce with any function in boost so it seems to me like a problem in `read_symlink` but I might be totally wrong about it, after all the boost library has pretty robust code.

Comment: @ep271p314 Right -- it's probably that read_symlink depends on some global that isn't getting initialized properly when you link boost statically.  A quick run through your favorite debugger should pinpoint the problem...